# Intuition behind the definition of normed B-Splines

Tags: numerical-methods, definition, intuition, interpolation, spline

> **Definition:** The normed B-Splines $N_k^m$ of degree $m\geq 1$ are recursively defined as
>
> $\hspace{4,5cm}N_k^0(x)=\begin{cases}
>       1, & \text{if}\ x\in[x_k,x_{k+1}) \\
>       0, & \text{else}
>     \end{cases}$
>
> and
>
> $\hspace{2cm} N^m_k(x)=\dfrac{x-x_k}{x_{k+m}-x_k}N^{m-1}_k(x)+\dfrac{x_{k+m+1}-x}{x_{k+m+1}-x_{k+1}}N_{k+1}^{m-1}(x)$
>
> where the $x_i$ are the spline knots in and around $[a,b]\in\mathbb{R}$ on which we wish to define our splines. The knots around $[a,b]$ where introduced to prevent having to do case distinctions at the edges for our normed B-Splines.

Now I'm able to work with this definition, but I would be interested in learning more about the intuition behind it and how people actually came up with this rather big formula and why we have to "norm" them.

Comment: Did you try to get a picture of what $N^1_m$ and $N^2_m$ look like? What are their supports, what their values at the node points?

Comment: Well I'm trying it right now but it would probably be helpful for others here too to have an explanation online.